# How to add a Button using HTML?

Tags: html, button

I'm trying to find out how can I add a button to my site using HTML, this is the code I'm using:

```
button = "Add To Cart";
```

but it is not working, is there anyone who can help me?

Note: I'm using html

Comment: That one line of code is not HTML.  It's really not clear what you're asking.

Comment: <button type="submit" >Add To Cart</button>

Comment: Thank you ajeetkumar, you can post the answer so that way I may accept it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add the `<button>` HTML tag.

```
<button>Add to Cart</button>
```

`button = "Add to Cart"` is not an HTML code.

Comment: You did a great job plop